# Elasticsearch 5.2.2 trouble starting on google compute engine

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine

ES version 5.2.2 and Discovery GCE 5.2.2

I have a GCE that has an internal and external IP. I installed ES 5.2.2 from source and then installed the Discovery GCE. I changed the network.host to 'gce' and added the project id, zone, etc of the GCE into elasticsearch.yml.

When I tried starting the instance using './bin/elasticsearch', I get the following error. 
Bootstrap tests are failing. Also, it has a message as '
Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: d7:0c:ef:bf:d0:7b:a6:95'

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, other generic questions, is it not possible to publish ES at external IP of the GCE? Sorry if this sounds too stupid I'm not a savvy in this area.

```
[2017-03-11T11:14:56,524][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [] initializing ...
[2017-03-11T11:14:56,596][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [dQjMwOl] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [9.5gb], net total_space [15.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2017-03-11T11:14:56,596][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [dQjMwOl] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-03-11T11:14:56,603][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] node name [dQjMwOl] derived from node ID [dQjMwOlrSYy5IxZaBai7WQ]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-03-11T11:14:56,605][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] version[5.2.2], pid[3989], build[f9d9b74/2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z], OS[Linux/4.4.21-90-default/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_112/25.112-b15]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,315][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,316][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,316][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,317][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,317][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,317][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,317][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,318][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,318][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,318][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-03-11T11:14:57,322][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [dQjMwOl] loaded plugin [discovery-gce]
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,506][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] initialized
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,506][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [dQjMwOl] starting ...
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,782][WARN ][i.n.u.i.MacAddressUtil ] Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: d7:0c:ef:bf:d0:7b:a6:95
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,935][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService ] [dQjMwOl] publish_address {10.140.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {10.140.0.2:9300}
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,943][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks ] [dQjMwOl] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,961][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [dQjMwOl] stopping ...
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,975][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [dQjMwOl] stopped
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,976][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [dQjMwOl] closing ...
[2017-03-11T11:14:59,987][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [dQjMwOl] closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase the file descriptors as per:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html
`root$ ulimit -n 65536`
and the max virtual mem:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html
`root$ sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 262144
root$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

or to make it permanent:
Edit /etc/sysctl.conf, put parameters inside
vm.max_map_count=2621444.

As for the "Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces", make sure you have api_host setting tied to a transport that is not localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Your answer, whilst correct, will be __greatly__ improved if you could include a snippet/example of how to increase the file descriptors and max virtual memory. Links are awesome, and it's good to note your sources, but try to make sure that your answer will be valid in the future if/when the link dies/moves. Good luck!